# SQLAlchemy Flask run code after insert/update/delete

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask

I am using Flask and a SQLAlchemy extension. Also I am using the declarative way to write my models as described in the extension's documentation.

For one of my models, I have some code I need to run after a new row has been inserted, updated or deleted. I was wondering how to do it? Ideally I would just add functions to the model.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at SQLAlchemy's [Mapper Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#mapper-events).  You can bind a callback function to the `after_insert`, `after_update`, and `after_delete` events.

Example:

```
from sqlalchemy import event

def after_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    # 'target' is the inserted object
    print(target.id_user)

event.listen(User, 'after_insert', after_insert_listener)
```